# Visual Studio 2017 warning for INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P while using googletest

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, googletest, parameterized-tests

I have a gtest test fixture for variable parameterized tests and I instantiate the test suite as below:

```
INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(Instantiation, Fixture, ::testing::Range(1, 100));
```

When I execute the tests, things work like I expect and the tests run 100 times with the right parameters.

However, in Visual Studio 2017, I get a warning (green underline) for `INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P` that informs me that `'Function definition for INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P not Found'`.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: Just ignore this. This is not compiler warning, but warning from parser which provides auto-completion in VS and so on. This parser didn't noticed that this is use of a macro and it thinks it is a function declaration.